# Copy symlink rather than directory in Vue/Webpack build process

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli

In my Vue project I'm trying to copy a symlink from either the /src folder or /public folder to the /dist folder during/after the build process. My vue.config.js file looks like this...

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  publicPath: undefined,
  outputDir: undefined,
  assetsDir: undefined,
  runtimeCompiler: undefined,
  productionSourceMap: undefined,
  parallel: undefined,
  css: undefined,
  chainWebpack: config => {
    config.resolve.symlinks(false),
    config.plugin('copy')
          .tap(args => {
            args[0].push({
              from: __dirname + '/src/w',
              to: __dirname + '/dist/w',
            })
            return args
          })
  }
}
```

But it copies the actual directory rather than a symlink to it. Any ideas on how to achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Seems like webpack now has a flag for this:

```
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      symlinks: false
    }
  }
}
```

[source](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/5275#issuecomment-599076562)